# Can I use `strlen()`, `strcpy()`, `strrev()`, `strcmp()` or `strcat()` when creating a kernel in C?

Tags: c, assembly, kernel

I am trying to make a kernel which has some functions that print out characters, draw, etc. And these functions will later be linked with assembly. I was wondering if I could still use these functions:
`strlen()`
`strcpy()`
`strrev()`
`strcmp()`
`strcat()`

Comment: A kernel is usually not linked with the standard C library, so these function needs to be implemented in a minimal library to be used by the kernel.

Comment: Yes, if you use a compiler that has them built-in, such as `gcc`. Consult the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). But note that _"Many of these functions are only optimized in certain cases; if they are not optimized in a particular case, a call to the library function is emitted. "_

Comment: And the reason is that a lot of the C standard library doesn't make sense to a kernel. `printf`? Nope. `malloc`? Nope. And those are just functions. The library also adds code that's run at startup that's probably inapplicable.

Comment: You can define your own versions of those, which GCC can use as a fallback when it doesn't inline.

`-ffreestanding` implies `-fno-builtin`, so also want to actually use `__builtin_strlen` everywhere except when you define it, which can optimize away for constant strings, for example.  Or compile to a call to an actual `strlen` function.

Comment: @PeterCordes I decided to just build off of some functions that I found in osdev.org

Comment: If you do not have any idea how to implement these functions yourself, I'm not sure if you will be able to pull off writing your own kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, I found this snippet of code from osdev.org, which I am going to build off of, to have the `strlen()` function, although I cant find a way to create the other functions that I listed in the title if this question.

```c
size_t strlen(const char* str) 
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while (str[len])
        len++;
    return len;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy` is similarly simple. The others you mention are hardly more complicated. It's all basically 5-6 lines functions.

Comment: Note this doesn't always work.  The compiler may notice "oh, the programmer is coding a strlen equivalent. I'll just replace it by a call to the library `strlen` function which must be better optimized than anything I could produce."  I think `-ffreestanding` would turn it off, but even in that case, it still applies to `memcpy`, I believe.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes I noticed that. I decided to rename the function to `get_string_size`

Answer (score 0):

Will this library work `#include <linux/string.h>` ?
`<string.h>` library cannot be used in kernel.
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/string.h#L48

look at the link, there is a strcmp function and others that you need.
I'm new so I'm not 100% sure. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: This question is about writing a custom kernel, not writing Linux kernel code.  If their project is GPLed (or they're not releasing it to anyone), then yeah they can copy Linux kernel code, but there's a lot of files to copy to find the arch-specific definitions.

Comment: @Peter Cordes You're right, I didn't pay attention to it. And that he only has the ability to write all these functions by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out after experimenting, that you can actually use some libraries, like `stdint.h` and `stdbool.h` even when making a kernel in C. Although this can be done, I have implemented my own versions of the functions that I asked about above...

Comment: Yeah, types are built-in to the compiler; C standard library functions like `strlen` aren't (unless they inline).  Things like `<endian.h>` for `le32toh()` will also normally have inline definitions, but a debug build may not always inline them.